# Authentication Middleware Slim 3.0

Tags: php, session, slim, slim-3

I am using a middleware to redirect to login page if session is not set.

```
$app->get('/dashboard', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
include_once('employee-portal/dashboard.php');
return $response;})->add(new AuthMiddleware('counter', true, $app->getContainer()));
```

and my middleware:

```
class AuthMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface{
private $min_role = 'counter';
private $redirect = true;
private $container = null;
public function __construct($role_required, $login_redirect, $container)
{
    $this->min_role = $role_required;
    $this->redirect = $login_redirect;
    $this->container = $container;
}
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
{
    if ($this->userIsAuthorised()) {
        return $next($request, $response);
    } else {
        if ($this->redirect) {
            /**
             * @var \Slim\Router router`
             */
            return $response->withRedirect(Details::getBaseUrl() . '/login' . '?ref=' . $request->getUri());
        }

        return $response->withStatus(401)->write("Sorry boss you are not authorised to see my secret");
    }

}

private function userIsAuthorised()
{
    if ($this->min_role == 'counter') {
        return true;
    } else if (SessionManager::isLoggedIn()) {
        if ($_SESSION['user_type']=='counter') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}  }
```

but this doesn't works.
i can even see the dashboard page without login. and even after login i cannot access the `$_SESSION['user_type']` session variable.

any help would be appriciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see `session_start()` anywhere.

Comment: its called in the namespace. SessionManager::isLoggedIn();

Comment: Is this called in your middleware class?

Comment: yeah. i have just edited my code. plz do have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `'counter'` into your AuthMiddleware constructor, causing it to always `return true` in the first `if()` statement of `userIsAuthorised()` method.

```
if ($this->min_role == 'counter')
```

will always be true because you set `$this->min = 'counter'` in your constructor.  Try rewriting the `new AuthMiddleware()` and constructor so that you just pass in the container.  Before calling the `new AuthMiddleware()` you can do the following:
    `$container['min_role'] = 'counter'` if you need it elsewhere in your app.